# PostgreSQL Mountain Lion socket issue

Tags: macos, postgresql, osx-mountain-lion

I've been trying to set up PostgreSQL on my system (OSX 10.8, clean install), but I'm running into trouble with using `psql`, `createdb`, etc. I've tried various solutions and none seem to work.

The install was successful, and I proceeded to fix the known sockets issue using the following:

```
mkdir /var/pgsql_socket 
sudo chown $USER /var/pgsql_socket
```

Then I edited `postgresql.conf`, set `unix_socket_directory` to

```
unix_socket_directory = '/var/pgsql_socket'
```

and restarted Pg.

That should apparently have fixed the socket issue, but I'm still getting:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Also, I've checked the status of the server, and it appears to be running, but I still get 'no such file or directory'

Any ideas?

Comment: Could Pg be listening on a different port? Check `postgresql.conf` - the `port` directive. Also, how did you install Pg? Heroku's Postgres.app? Homebrew? The EnterpriseDB installer? Something else?

Comment: Used Homebrew, but also installed then got rid of Postgres.app .... the issue has been there since the initial Homebrew install though

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the error message, the `psql` command that appears first in the `$PATH` has `/tmp` as the hard-coded  default unix socket directory.

Since the actual directory is in fact `/var/pgsql_socket`, you should tell it explicitly rather than relying on the default:

```
$ psql -h /var/pgsql_socket [other options]
```

The same applies to other client-side commands like `createdb`, `dropdb`, `createuser`...

If you don't want to specify `-h` each time, it can be put into the `PGHOST` environment variable.

Some people also solve this by using TCP connections to `localhost` rather than using the Unix socket directory.

The root cause of this issue would be that after installing PostgreSQL on Mac OS X, the system ends up having two different instances of the postgres client set (the `libpq` library, `psql` and other associated utilities), one that is bundled with MacOS and the other that comes with the PostgreSQL installer.

Therefore yet another method is to change your `$PATH` so that the `psql` installed with PostgreSQL gets choosen before the one installed with the system (presumably `/usr/bin/psql`).

Comment: I had the exact same problem, and I only used the Postgres.app. The issue (as Daniel alludes to) is that there is a default installation with Mountain Lion, and there are indeed two different instances of the postgres client. I made an alias to the Postgres app's version by placing this in my .bash_profile: 

`alias psql=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/psql`, and that's done the trick.

Comment: Setting PGHOST to localhost solved my issue. Even though I had set the socket folder in postgresql.conf, psql always tried to connect to /tmp. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same issue when installing PostgreSQL 9.2 via Homebrew. `psql` that comes with this build looks to `/tmp` for a socket when called without any options.

I didn't feel like adding any new environment variables like `PGHOST` or creating aliases for `psql`. There's nothing wrong with doing any of these things, but I just didn't feel like adding to the clutter of my environment.

So, why not just set `unix_socket_directory` in `postgresql.conf` to `/tmp`? I did:

```
unix_socket_directory = '/tmp'      # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''             # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777     # begin with 0 to use octal notation
```

After a reload, I can just run `$ psql` with no `-h` option, without having added an alias or environment variable.

Comment: I like the idea of this solution, but it didn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and after doing what you'd done I also had to change my path so that /usr/local/bin (where Homebrew puts everything) comes before /usr/bin.  I don't know why this isn't the default anymore, but it's easy to change.

```
sudo vi /etc/paths
```

then edit the file to have the /usr/local/bin line at the top.

Or alternately if you just want this change to happen for your specific user account, edit your ~/.bash_profile file:

```
touch ~/.bash_profile
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

and add this line: `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`

then run `source ~/.bash_profile` for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

See accepted answer for question/link below. Worked for me, but note the setting to change is unix_socket_directories (plural) not unix_socket_directory as stated.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21587/postgresql-is-running-locally-but-i-cannot-connect-why