# Rails can't see my Postgres database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to load a Rails 3.2 project on my Macbook and I'm having difficulty. I installed Postgres 9.1.4 via `brew`. After putting `/usr/local/bin` in the front of my `$PATH`, I can now get into Postgres from the command line via `psql`.

However, in my Rails project, when I run:

```
rake db:create:all
```

I get the following error:

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.S.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Well that file indeed does not exist. Yet I can access the database via the command line with `psql`.

Why is it looking in that area, and what can I do to make it look in the proper place (whatever that is) for Postgres?

Comment: can you provide us with your database.yml configuration file

Comment: Did you search Stack Overflow for this first? This is a depressingly common issue on Mac systems, especially for Homebrew users.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is depressingly common on OS X systems for users of Homebrew and Postgres.app.

What happens is that your Rails 'Pg' gem gets compiled against the old PostgreSQL version Apple pre-installs on some Mac OS X versions, rather than the version you installed yourself. This happens because the `PATH` has the Apple version of `pg_config` on it before the version you installed.

Any of these alternatives will work:

- Recompile the Pg gem to use the correct `libpq` by setting your `PATH` so that the right `pg_config` is on it before compiling (best option);
- Set an explicit socket directory when you connect with `host: /tmp`, or with `psql` etc `-h /tmp/`;
- Use TCP/IP: `host: localhost`, `psql -h localhost`, etc;

You can find more detail here:

- [PostgreSQL Mountain Lion socket issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12032585/398670)

Comment: Thanks Craig. I didn't think to look for Mountain Lion as it was my 2nd Mountain Lion install. Now that I think about it I may have removed the Mac version first on the first install.

Answer (score 0):

Check your *database.yml* file. Probably a bad configuration

Comment: Rather, it's a bad Pg gem configuration that can be *worked around* by setting an explicit `host` in Rails's `database.yml`.